# Webpack 2 Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module

Tags: javascript, module, webpack-2

When I want to create my bundle.js with:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

I get the following error

> ERROR in ./dev/js/source/scripts/components/TextInput.js Module not
>   found: Error: Cannot resolve module
>   'source/scripts/components/IconButton' in
>   /Users/sebastien/Documents/Javascript/Tests/MyApp/dev/js/source/scripts/components
>   @ ./dev/js/source/scripts/components/TextInput.js 4:18-65
>
> ERROR in ./dev/js/source/scripts/components/TextInput.js Module not
>   found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'source/scripts/SDK/classNames' in
>   /Users/sebastien/Documents/Javascript/Tests/MyApp/dev/js/source/scripts/components
>   @ ./dev/js/source/scripts/components/TextInput.js 15:17-57

The project tree is the following

```
/Users/sebastien/Documents/Javascript/Tests/MyApp
- webpack.config.js 
- dev
 - js 
  - index.js
  - source
   - scripts
    - components
     - TextInput.js
     - IconButton.js
    - SDK
     - classNames.js
```

In TextInput.js there's the following statement

```
import IconButton from "source/scripts/components/IconButton";
```

and my webpack.config.js contains the following

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './src',
        port: 8080
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: './dev/js/index.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['babel'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: 'src',
        filename: 'js/bundle.min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
    ]
};
```

How can I configure webpack to add the path ./dev/js to search for modules? I have tried with:

```
- modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./dev/js"), "node_modules"]
```

without any success. Can you help?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import IconButton from "./source/scripts/components/IconButton";
```

and see if that helps.

or

```
import IconButton from "../source/scripts/components/IconButton";
```

but the first one should probably work. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, it helps but I don't want to change the source code of .js files located under the directory scripts. 
I'm not the owner of these *.js files (they are delivered by another team). I would like to solve the issue only with webpack configuration (if it's possible?).

Comment: Eh, sorry then, can't help you. I thought that the answer I've provided might work, because I had the exact same issue while working in React. I've never did really used webpack, but maybe if you search the error in Google, something like "webpack module not found fix path in config" or something similar, or simply wait for someone to give appropriate answer.

Comment: Don't be sorry. I appreciate always when someone answer and try to help.